# How to fix an "error MSB4068: The element <NDepend> is unrecognized" when trying to create an migration in command line (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add addListModel --project <path to the .csproj file>
```

Error:

```
 error MSB4068: The element <NDepend> is unrecognized, or not supported in this context.
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
```

Dotnet core version 2.1